# pg_dump: How to set username and password for the *.sql output file?

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a local copy of an external postgres database. I am asked for the password of the local copy. Where can I set/access this password? I never set a password.

```
pg_dump -h external_hostname -p 5432 -U postgres db > db_copy.sql

createdb -p 5432 -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres db_copy
```

I get the error

```
createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL: password authentication failed for user “postgres”
```

Comment: A common solution is: go to `/ect/postgres/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf` and change 'peer' to 'trust' on Line 85:
Instead of `Local all postgres peer` it should read `Local all postgres trust`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should find your pg_hba.conf file with

> show hba_file;

Its place can be change but if you use debian based system, must be about `etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_hba.conf`

open this file and change

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
```

to

```
local   all             postgres                                trust
```

After all you should reload postgresql service from root, or easy way to reload is that, you run this select query by open psql :

```
select pg_reload_conf();
```

Comment: Thank you @berkancetin ! Unfortunately it doesn't work. I can find the pg_hba.conf file, I have changed it and reloaded. I work with Windows10 and have postgresql 12 installed.

Comment: can you try 127.0.0.1 insted of local